# In the below program I was expected Infinite loop as a output. But output is 0, please help me with explain the concept behind it

Tags: c

```
void main()
{   
     int i;
     int s=0;
     while(i<30)
     s+=i;
     i++;
     printf("Sum is %d",s);
}
```

/*output is 0,how? I was expecting infinite loop.*/

Comment: Learn how to use your debugger now.  Don't write any more code until you know.

Answer (score 7):

`i` is uninitialized. It can have any value. If it has a value greater/equal than 30, the loop will not execute and `s` remains 0.

Comment: It is also possible that the compiler sees the condition with the uninitialized variable, cut the loop out and so it can simplify the whole program to `puts("Sum is 0")`.

Comment: @mch, I don;t think the compiler is allowed to do that. The uninitalized variable could be smaller than 30 or could be zero. I could do such a thing for example to seed a randomizer. In VC I do get a warning about it, however, which is the correct thing to do.

Comment: the compiler is allowed to do this, because it is undefined behaviour. A compiler programer wrote that it is common practice: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html

Comment: But when i declare 'i' without initialization and print it first time then the value is some how negative like -27528 type...It means the condition would become true

Comment: Rahul, an uninitialized variable can have _any_ value, positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

```
void main()
{   
     int i;
     int s=0;
     while(i<30)
     s+=i;
     i++;
     printf("Sum is %d",s);
}
```

`i` is not being initialized properly, leading to undefined behaviour. Change it to:

```
int main(void)
{   
     int i = 0;
     int s=0;
     while(i<30)  // Infinite loop per OP's expectation
       s+=i;
     i++;
     printf("Sum is %d",s);
return 0;
}
```

Note (Thanks @MikeCAT): To avoid implementation based messing, replace `void main()` with `int main(void)`.

Comment: Note: `void main()` is implementation-defined and `int main(void)` is better.

Comment: @mch I think a long day at work is wearing on me. Fixed, finally now, hopefully.

Comment: With the suggested fix, the output is an infinite loop.

Comment: @chux exactly what OP expected :D

Comment: Well - face palm on my part.

Comment: @chux with the suggested fix, there is no output at all, because the loop runs forever and there is no `printf` inside of the loop.

Comment: Yes - mis-comment, meant  "the while loop  is an infinite loop".  Its all ready a long day for me too.

Comment: @chux OP said he was expecting an infinite loop, and asked for help to make it work. I provided that. Why he *wants* an infinite loop is unknown to me, and not important in the scope of the question.

Comment: @chux no problem though, can happen on a long day :D

Comment: Uncommented code that does unusual things like `while(i<30) s+=i;` is prone to mis-interpretation with a quick review - of which I am guilty of.  Recommend commenting this unusual line of code.

Comment: @chux Im heading home from work now, so if you want to edit a comment in, feel free to.